# Limit in the number of sharing wishlist in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.6, wishlist

I just found that the 'share wishlist' button on my wishlist page is gone after sending emails for the number of times set in the wishlist configuration in the backend.

[image]

In other words, if the default number is 10, I can share the wishlist only 10 times and I can't use the feature forever.

However, according to their document, the number means the maximum number of emails that can be sent in a single batch not the number of emails sent separately.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/b2b/user_guide/configuration/customers/wishlist.html

So you can't use the 'Share wishlist' feature anymore after you send the list to 10 people or send it to one by one up to 10. Although you add a new product after removing the old one, you still can't use the feature.

I understand I can increase the number up to 10000 but it's ridiculous that they limit the number of lifetime sharing lists.

My magento version is 2.2.6.

Can you please share your wisdom to resolve this issue if there is any?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Create a cron and deleted those data daily basis. So user can share wishlist daily 10 (comes from setting)

Comment: I think that's a good idea! Thanks!